# Force browser to interpret XHR response as gzip

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, gzip

I'm writing a client-only JavaScript application that downloads (via XHR) relatively large JSON datasets for display. I'd like to gzip these datasets in advance to save on space and bandwidth (e.g. `mydata.json.gz`).

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the server configuration, and it sends `Content-Type: application/x-gzip` headers for my `.json.gz` files, rather than the correct pair of `Content-Encoding: gzip` and `Content-Type: application/json`. Because of this, my application receives the raw gzipped data, rather than something I can pass along to `JSON.parse()`.

I'm aware of a few pure-JavaScript Gzip implementations (e.g. [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako)) that could presumably get the job done, but is there any way to trick the browser into decoding it for me that won't require an otherwise unnecessary 45KB library?

Comment: Since Content-Encoding: gzip is HTTP protocol level setting. I don't think browser exposes any API to decompress stream. I know you have limitation to change http response header in your server. But the best way is still to config right http response header is your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware of a few pure-JavaScript Gzip implementations (e.g. pako) that could presumably get the job done

Use one of those

> but is there any way to trick the browser into decoding it for me that won't require an otherwise unnecessary 45KB library?

No.

The server is saying "Here is a gzip file" and not "Here is a JSON file that is being transmitted using a gzip encoding".

You have to change the HTTP response headers to get the browser to decode it transparently.

Comment: I suspected as much, but figured it might be worth asking anyway. Thanks!